# VS Team Explorer merge conflicts

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, team-explorer

When merging our develop branch into my feature branch `develop --> feature` in `Visual Studio`, I get a merge conflict.
I have the possibility to choose from `Take Source` and `Keep Target`.

I want to take the file from the `develop` branch. Which one is the correct option?

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In this case, you should `Take Source`. The "Source" is the `develop` branch and the "Target" is the `feature` branch.

Comment: It's way too ambiguous in Visual Studio which is the source branch and which is the target branch. Microsoft can do better than this - I feel they should throw the branch name on there too. It's just a little too tricky. At least it all works - but the UI in all of the VS merge process could be a bit better. Lots of little UI quirks they could fix.

Comment: For instance, when doing a merge and resolving conflicts, when you click on one side to check it out, the window auto scrolls down - for what reason I don't know - and you lose your place and have to scroll back up. Just one example of these little problems (perhaps it's by design for some reason - very annoying though).

Comment: AND, when you do 'compare files', it gives you a nice little sidebar showing you all the red and green areas of each file. But when you click 'merge' to actually do the step through and mark a checkbox next to each change you want to keep, this helpful sidebar guide is no longer there - making it much easier to make a mistake. You have to visually scroll through the whole file and look for any green or red areas, whereas with the guide you could quickly tell 'hey - there's a green area down there, let me scroll to it'.

Comment: Hopefully Microsoft will enhance it in feature: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/502400/resolve-conflict-source-and-target-is-confusing.html

Answer (score 1):

I found @Kyle Vassella 's comment, above, worked best for me, i.e. **use the "Merge"-button**.
It is simple, powerful and the ambiguity of the other options can be ignored.

I first **"Compared files"** (or "diff'd" them) using the above UI - just to get a feel for what I was dealing with.  In my case, I could have then selected the Master version for one file and the branch for the other one and all would have been fine, but I would have lost a few comment tweaks and some tidying up of the code.  **Clicking on "Merge" allowed me to view both versions + VisualStudio2017's best guess at what the merged file should look like** - its guess was extremely good.  I could have just resolved 3 or 4 minor conflicts and accepted everything else.  The UI provide buttons to find the next/previous Conflict and the next/previous Change. The former are the main thing, the latter are handy for double-checking everything.

I thought VS2017 Teams GIT lacked proper interactive MERGE capability - I was wrong, once found it is actually surprisingly good and simple to use.  Harummph!